# Send some special HTTP code when a server is marked as down in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I use [`down`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) flag to check some API servers as off for a reason.
Is it possible to send a custom HTTP code in this case so that consumers of the API accurately know that the API server is down intentionally? Default code is, what I see - 502.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one among from the [list(5xx)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

or you can send one of your made custom code(ex - 512) which will let the white screen with error code can be found in the network tab(ctrl+shift+i).

You can make use of [fastcgi_intercep_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors), [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) and [named location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directives for the above use case( please check the below code).

```
...
location ~ /.*\.php {
  ...
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 502 @custom_error;
  ...
}

location @custom_error {
  return 5xx;
}
...
```

If you use proxy_pass, then you can use [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive.